# stand-alone lazy loading images (no framework based)

Tags: javascript, image, lazy-loading, optimization

I look after a site which by nature has to load quite a lot of images and content on the page. We have decreased the number of elements and graphical layout images as much as we can, so we are now looking at ways to increase the page load in the browser.

Does anyone know any code for lazy loading images that doesn't require a framework such as jQuery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is my own. Have Fun.

**Tested:** IE 5.5+, FF 2+, Chrome, Opera 9.6+

**Usage:**

1. your lazyloaded images should have their real src in a thumb attribute
2. Just include the javascript file inline or externally.
3. If you don't want to use it on your entire page, you can do:

   ```
    LazyImg().destroy(); // stop global fetching
    LazyImg("watch-only-this-div");
   ```

   Note: when you include the file a global instance is already created watchin the whole document. You need to stop that first and start you own instance.

   4. set a custom offset for prefetching (how far below the fold the image should be fetched)

      ```
       // watch the whole document
       // prefetch offset: 300px
       LazyImg(document, 300);
      ```

**Code:**

```
//
//  LAZY Loading Images 
//
//  Handles lazy loading of images in one or more targeted divs, 
//  or in the entire page. It also keeps track of scrolling and 
//  resizing events, and removes itself if the work is done. 
//
//  Licensed under the terms of the MIT license.
//
//  (c) 2010 Balázs Galambosi
//

(function(){

// glocal variables
var window    = this, 
    instances = {},
    winH;

// cross browser event handling
function addEvent( el, type, fn ) {
  if ( window.addEventListener ) {
    el.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
  } else if ( window.attachEvent ) {
    el.attachEvent( "on" + type, fn );
  } else {
    var old = el["on" + type];
    el["on" + type] = function() { old(); fn(); };
  }
}

// cross browser event handling
function removeEvent( el, type, fn ) {
  if ( window.removeEventListener ) {
    el.removeEventListener( type, fn, false );
  } else if ( window.attachEvent ) {
    el.detachEvent( "on" + type, fn );
  }
}

// cross browser window height
function getWindowHeight() {
  if ( window.innerHeight ) {
    winH = window.innerHeight;
  } else if ( document.documentElement.clientHeight ) {
    winH = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if ( document.body && document.body.clientHeight ) {
    winH = document.body.clientHeight;
  } else {        // fallback:
    winH = 10000; // just load all the images
  }
  return winH;
}

// getBoundingClientRect alternative
function findPos(obj) {
  var top  = 0;
  if (obj && obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
      top += obj.offsetTop || 0;
      top -= obj.scrollTop || 0;
    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent); // 
    return { "top" : top };
  }
}

// top position of an element
var getTopPos = (function() {
  var dummy = document.createElement("div");
  if ( dummy.getBoundingClientRect ) {
    return function( el ) { 
      return el.$$top || el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    };
  } else {
    return function( el ) { 
      return el.$$top || findPos( el ).top;
    };
  }
})();

// sorts images by their vertical positions
function img_sort( a, b ) {
  return getTopPos( a ) - getTopPos( b );
}

// let's just provide some interface 
// for the outside world
var LazyImg = function( target, offset ) {

  var imgs,    // images array (ordered)
      last,    // last visible image (index)
      id,      // id of the target element
      self;    // this instance

  offset = offset || 200; // for prefetching

  if ( !target ) {
    target = document;
    id = "$document";
  } else if ( typeof target === "string" ) {
    id = target;
    target = document.getElementById( target );
  } else {
    id = target.id || "$undefined";
  }

  // return if this instance already exists
  if ( instances[id] ) {
    return instances[id];
  }

  // or make a new instance
  self = instances[id] = {

    // init & reset
    init: function() {
      imgs = null;
      last = 0;
      addEvent( window, "scroll", self.fetchImages );
      self.fetchImages();
      return this;
    },

    destroy: function() { 
      removeEvent( window, "scroll", self.fetchImages );
      delete instances[id];
    },

    // fetches images, starting at last (index)
    fetchImages: function() {

      var img, temp, len, i;

      // still trying to get the target
      target = target || document.getElementById( id );

      // if it's the first time
      // initialize images array
      if ( !imgs && target ) {

        temp = target.getElementsByTagName( "img" ); 

        if ( temp.length ) {
          imgs = [];
          len  = temp.length;
        } else return;

        // fill the array for sorting
        for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
          img = temp[i];
          if ( img.nodeType === 1 && img.getAttribute("thumb") ) {

              // store them and cache current
              // positions for faster sorting
              img.$$top = getTopPos( img );
              imgs.push( img );
          }
        }
        imgs.sort( img_sort );
      }

      // loop through the images
      while ( imgs[last] ) {

        img = imgs[last];

        // delete cached position
        if ( img.$$top ) img.$$top = null;

        // check if the img is above the fold
        if ( getTopPos( img ) < winH + offset )  {

          // then change the src 
          img.src = img.getAttribute("thumb");
          last++;
        }
        else return;
      }

      // we've fetched the last image -> finished
      if ( last && last === imgs.length )  {
        self.destroy();
      }
    }  
  };
  return self.init();
};

// initialize
getWindowHeight();
addEvent( window, "load",   LazyImg().fetchImages );
addEvent( window, "resize", getWindowHeight       ); 
LazyImg();

window.LazyImg = LazyImg;

}());
```

Comment: sorry, what do you mean as 'thumb' attribute on an img?

Comment: `<img src="pixel.gif" thumb="real_image_to_be_loaded.jpg">`. If the markup stays the same, the browser would usually download the images.

Comment: hm, thanks for the code, trouble is that then bots will see pixel.gif everywhere and not the actual files and thus index them incorrectly?

Comment: Starting from your code, then rewriting it all I have done a similar lazy loader : https://github.com/fasterize/lazyload

Comment: Yes for the sake of simplicity you can throttle the scroll event handler and check for every image's position. Mine is designed to work for large number of images, doing most of the work beforehand by sorting images by their position.

Comment: Yes but : You then have to wait for full page onload/dom ready to check for images and most of the times you'll end up having images showing up too late. Also, image positions will change the more you add images, onload position can be different as soon as you started showing some images.

Answer (score 2):

"thumb" does not validate when using XHTML. I changed it to "title" and it seems to be working ok.